# Why is my Image element in React Native (IOS) not shown on load?

Tags: image, react-native, render

I'm working on a React Native app and using a simple Image element in my main view.

For Android, the image is rendered as soon as the View loads. But for IOS (both emulator and actual device) it does not render unless I click into an input element or button.

Is this something expected for development environments? I followed the FB GitHub tutorial and haven't changed any significant setting at all.

```
<View style={MyStyle.imageContainer}>
    <Image source={require('./public/Logo.png')}
         style={MyStyle.image}/>
</View>

  image: {
    width: 225, 
    height: 140,
  },
  imageContainer: {
    flex: 3,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

Comment: Is this inside a ScrollView/FlatList or inside a `react-navigation` scene?

Comment: It's only inside another View (which is the main View). No Scroll, Flat or scenes. Very simple setup.

Comment: Please share your complete component code. The code you have given here is working fine on both ios and android.

Comment: Seems like it was a temporary laggy rendering, the issue was gone eventually. Thanks both.